# How to clear the screen before rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore

Seeing issues while developing a real time wallboard using react . I am displaying 2 components one after another Dashboard1( a table with data), Dashboard2(another table with data) with 3 secs time interval. My parent component is Dashboard it connects to my firestore DB to receive real-time updates and sends this data to Dashboard1 component and then Dashboard 1 renders its data and after 3 seconds calls Dashboard2 with the same data passed to it by Dashboard using props.history.push().I am seeing 2 issues here. The component Dashboard 2 is always rendered above Dashboard1.Like when i scroll down the page ,i can still see Dashboard1 at the bottom. How to clear off the page before rendering Dashboard1 and 2 .So that i just see a single component at a time on the screen.Below is my code for App, Dashboard ,Dashboard1 and Dashboard2.I am also seeing Dashboard 2 is being rendered multiple times in the console logs.
Kindly help me to fix these 2 issues:

```
App.js:
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard'
import Dashboard1 from './components/Dashboard1'
import Dashboard2 from './components/Dashboard2'



class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('App')
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard} />
          <Route exact path='/Dashboard1' component={Dashboard1} />
          <Route exact path='/Dashboard2' component={Dashboard2} />
          <Dashboard />
       </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

export default(App)

Dashboard.js:
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import Dashboard1 from './Dashboard1'
import Dashboard2 from './Dashboard2'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import { compose } from 'redux'



class Dasboard extends Component {

  render() {
    console.log('Dashboard')
    const { agents } = this.props

    if (!agents) {
      return null
    }
    return (
      <Dashboard1 data={agents}/>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    agents: state.firestore.data.agent_groups
  }
}


export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect([
    { collection: 'agent_groups' }
  ])
)(Dasboard)

Dashboard1.js:
import React from 'react'
import Table from '../layouts/Table'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'



const Dashboard1 = (props) => {
  console.log('Dashboard1')
  setTimeout(() => {
    props.history.push({
      pathname: '/Dashboard2',
      state: { data: props.data.WFM_Inbound_Sales.agents }})

  }, 3000);
  return (
    <div className="dashboard1">
      <Table
        data={props.data.WFM_Inbound_Sales.agents}  
        headers={[
            {
              name: 'Agent',
              prop: 'name'
            },
            {
              name: 'Total calls',
              prop: 'InboundCalls'
            }
          ]}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default withRouter(Dashboard1)

Dashboard2.js:
import React from 'react'
import Table from '../layouts/Table'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'


const Dashboard2 = (props) => {
  console.log('Dashboard2')
  setTimeout(() => {
    props.history.push('/')
  }, 3000);
  return (
    <div className="dashboard2">
      <Table
        data={props.location.state.data}
        headers={[
          {
            name: 'Agent',
            prop: 'name'
          },
          {
            name: 'Status',
            prop: 'state'
          },
          {
            name: 'Time in status',
            prop: 'TimeInCurrentState'
          }
        ]}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default withRouter(Dashboard2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use switch which will render only one route of the given set like this

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('App')
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard} />
            <Route exact path='/Dashboard1' component={Dashboard1} />
            <Route exact path='/Dashboard2' component={Dashboard2} />
          </Switch>
          <Dashboard />
       </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

Check the doc [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch)

Comment: Hi Mabhijith,Thanks for your response ,I used switch but still 2 components are stacked on each other in the screen when I rredirect the currnt component to another using props.history.push().Screenshot:

Comment: imported: import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

Comment: and wrapped my Routes inside Switch:           <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard} />
            <Route exact path='/Dashboard1' component={Dashboard1} />
            <Route exact path='/Dashboard2' component={Dashboard2} />
          </Switch>

Comment: If you still have any problems create a codesandbox project and share the link I will check

Comment: yes i still have problems.I both the components are in the same screen one after another.The old component is not getting unmounted.

Comment: Hi Mabhijith, uploaded my code to this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/z511rpn44?fontsize=14 .Kindly help me

Comment: Dashboard component has Dashboard1 component which will be displayed always because you have it along with routes so remove <Dashboard/> in App.js

Comment: Thanks Mabhijith, that fixed the issue .So its not the way the components were unmounted.Since i had <Dashboard /> inside the router.It was always rendering the Dashboard component which routes to Dashboard1 .So it was always there in the screen.